# Boost::Regex Segfault (I think)

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm having an issue with some C++ code that I'm running. Basically, it works fine with most inputs, but with certain inputs it segfaults after my main function returns. This has been... puzzling. I stopped the run at the segfault to get the stack trace, and it returned this:

```
#0 malloc_consolidate() at /build/eglibc-oGUzwX/eglibc-2.19/malloc/malloc.c:4151
#1 _int_free() at /build/eglibc-oGUzwX/eglibc-2.19/malloc/malloc.c:4057
#2 boost::re_detail::mem_block_cache::~mem_block_cache()() at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.54.0
#3 __cxa_finalize() at /build/eglibc-oGUzwX/eglibc-2.19/stdlib/cxa_finalize.c:56
#4 ??() at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.54.0
#5 ??() at 
#6 _dl_fini() at /build/eglibc-oGUzwX/eglibc-2.19/elf/dl-fini.c:252
```

This made me think that I must be doing something wrong with boost regex, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. The way I'm using regex is that users can input a bunch of strings. Those strings could just be normal text, or they could be regular expressions. Because of this, I basically interact with all the inputs as regular expressions. But what if a user gave a string that was intended as plain text but had a character that could be interpreted differently as a regular expression? What I do is go through all plain text input strings and escape all those characters.

Here's the code that I'm working with. This is my main:

```
int
main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    // Process input arguments
    // The desired input is numVertices (int), graph density (double between 0 and 1), halfLoss (double), total loss (double),
    // position expanse (double, m), velocity expanse (double, m/s)
    int num_vertices;
    double graph_density ;
    double half_loss;
    double total_loss;
    double position_expanse;
    double velocity_expanse;

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        num_vertices = 48;
        graph_density = 1;
        half_loss = 200000;
        total_loss = 400000;
        position_expanse = 400000;
        velocity_expanse = 10000;
    }
    else
    {
        if (argc != 7)
        {
            std::cerr << "Need 6 input arguments" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        std::istringstream ss(argv[1]);
        num_vertices;
        if (!(ss >> num_vertices))
            std::cerr << "First input must be an integer" << std::endl;

        graph_density = read_double_input(argv[2]);
        half_loss = read_double_input(argv[3]);
        total_loss = read_double_input(argv[4]);
        position_expanse = read_double_input(argv[5]);
        velocity_expanse = read_double_input(argv[6]);
    }

    // Determine how many edges to create
    int num_edges = (int) ( (graph_density * num_vertices * (num_vertices - 1)) + 0.5 );

    // Create the edges
    int edges_created = 0;
    std::set<std::pair<int, int> > edge_set;
    while (edge_set.size() < num_edges)
    {

        // Pick a random start vertex and end vertex
        int start_vertex = rand() % num_vertices;
        int end_vertex = rand() % num_vertices;

        // Make sure the start and end vertices are not equal
        while (start_vertex == end_vertex)
        {
            end_vertex = rand() % num_vertices;
        }

        // Insert the new edge into our set of edges
        edge_set.insert(std::pair<int, int>(start_vertex, end_vertex));

    }

    // Create connection handler
    ConnectionHandler conn_handler;

    // Create lists for from and to vertices
    std::vector<std::string> from_list;
    std::vector<std::string> to_list;

    // Add connections to from and to lists
    for (std::set<std::pair<int, int> >::const_iterator edge_it = edge_set.begin(), end_it = edge_set.end(); edge_it != end_it; ++edge_it)
    {
        int start_vertex = edge_it->first;
        int end_vertex = edge_it->second;
        from_list.push_back("Radio" + int_to_string(start_vertex));
        to_list.push_back("Radio" + int_to_string(end_vertex));
    }

    // Read the list into the connection handler
    conn_handler.read_connection_list(true, from_list, to_list);    
    return 0;

}
```

This code has this ConnectionHandler object that I created. Here's the header for that:

```
#ifndef CLCSIM_CONNECTIONHANDLER_HPP_
#define CLCSIM_CONNECTIONHANDLER_HPP_

#include <models/network/NetworkTypes.hpp>
#include <generated/xsd/NetworkModelInterfaceConfig.hpp>

namespace clcsim
{

typedef std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string> > ConnectionFilter;

class ConnectionHandler
{

public:

    ConnectionHandler();
    ~ConnectionHandler();

    void read_connection_list(const bool is_white_list, const std::vector<std::string> &from_radios, const std::vector<std::string> &to_radios);


private:

    ConnectionFilter filter_;
    std::set<std::string> from_list_;
    std::set<std::string> to_list_;
    bool is_white_list_;

};

} // namespace clcsim

#endif // CLCSIM_CONNECTIONHANDLER_HPP_
```

And here's the source:

```
#include <models/network/ConnectionHandler.hpp>
#include <oasis/framework/exceptions/ConfigurationException.h>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

namespace clcsim 
{

ConnectionHandler::
ConnectionHandler()
{
}

ConnectionHandler::
~ConnectionHandler()
{
    std::cout << "Destructing conn handler" << std::endl;
}

void 
ConnectionHandler::
read_connection_list(
    const bool is_white_list, 
    const std::vector<std::string> &from_radios, 
    const std::vector<std::string> &to_radios)
{

    std::cout << "Reading the connection list" << std::endl;

    // Make sure the size of both the input vectors are the same
    std::size_t from_radio_size = from_radios.size();
    std::size_t to_radio_size = to_radios.size();
    if (from_radio_size != to_radio_size)
    {
        throw ofs::ConfigurationException("Error while initializing the "
                                          "Network model: "
                                          "Connections in from/to lists don't align"
                                         );
    }

    // Create a regular expression/replacement to find all characters in a non-regular expression
    // that would be interpreted as special characters in a regular expression. Replace them with
    // escape characters
    const boost::regex esc("[.$|()\\[\\]{}*+?\\\\]");
    const std::string rep("\\\\&");

    // Iterate through the specified connections
    for (int i = 0; i < from_radio_size; ++i)
    {

        std::string from_string = boost::regex_replace(from_radios[i], esc, rep, boost::match_default | boost::format_sed);
        std::string to_string = boost::regex_replace(to_radios[i], esc, rep, boost::match_default | boost::format_sed);
        //std::cout << "From " << from_string << " to " << to_string << std::endl;
        filter_[from_string].insert(to_string);
        //filter_[from_radios.at(i)].insert(to_radios.at(i));
    }

    std::cout << "Got here" << std::endl;

}


} // namespace clcsim
```

Sorry for so much code.

I saw some similar threads related to segfaults with boost::regex. In those examples, the users had really simple code that just created a regex and matched it and ran into an error. It turned out the issue was related to the Boost versioning. I tried to see if I could replicate those sorts of errors, but those simple examples worked just fine for me. So... I'm pretty stumped. I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean by "I stopped the run at the segfault".  If you have a segfault then the *system* will stop the run.  If you're running under a debugger then you should indeed then be able to get a stack trace showing the locus of the fault, but if *you* stop the program before the system does, then you cannot know that your stack trace characterizes the location of the yet-to-come segfault.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, thanks for correcting me. I ran it under a debugger and it stopped at the error and provided me a stack trace.

Comment: I see eglibc in your stack trace.  Is your software stack (boost, C++ compiler, C++ runtime, etc.) all consistent in being built for eglibc?  That glibc variant is now discontinued, and you might run into trouble if you mix software and libraries built against different C libraries.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting point. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, so it looks like eglibc is still the C library for that. I'm not quite sure how to figure out how Boost was built, though. Do you know how I can figure that out? Or would you just recommend rebuilding Boost?

Comment: Rebuilding boost is a bit of a pain, but that's certainly one way you could be confident that it's built for eglibc.  I think that's grasping at straws, though.

Comment: The most likely way to end up with mismatched software would be if you get a package by some means other than via Ubuntu's package management system, from one of its official repositories.  For example, some third-party software ships precompiled, with its own copies of Boost and / or other libraries.  If you're not careful, you could end up using different libraries than you think you're using.

Comment: Recent Debian has gone back to glibc, so if there is any C library incompatibility then software built for such Debian might not be compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: this has just happened to me too as i tried to upgrade our codebase from boost 1.56.0 to boost 1.62.0

Comment: In times like these it can be useful to run it through valgrind as well for any other additional hints you might get right before the segfault.

Comment: How about providing a [MCVE]!?

Comment: So I solved the issue, but it was probably not in the most efficient way. I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04. That updated me from eglibc to glibc, and now I don't have the issue. I think the issue did relate to a conflict between using glibc to build Boost and eglibc to build my program, but I can't positively confirm that that would have fixed things. Thanks a lot for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of removing this from the "Unanswered" list, I'm going to post the answer that was provided in the comments instead of here. The OP determined that the suggestion that Boost linked against eglibc was indeed conflicting with the rest of the code linked against glibc. As such, the OP found that upgrading his OS so that eglibc linked libraries were no longer in use fixed the problem.